# How can i have the same radius for each point of series with hover?

Tags: highcharts, hover

How can i have the same radius for each point of series with hover ?

If hover on point of series, the radius of point it will be different, and it will have also a linewidth...

i would like to have a point with same radius and GREY color

http://jsfiddle.net/1qj26hxw/

```
 plotOptions: {
                scatter: {                      
                 marker: {                     
                        states: {
                            hover: {    
                                radius: null,
                                radiusPlus: 0,
                                lineWidth: null,
                                lineWidthPlus: 0,
                                fillColor: {
                                    radialGradient: {
                                                    cx: 0.5,
                                                    cy: 0.3,
                                                    r: 0.5
                                                    },
                                        stops: [
                                                [0, "#ffffff"],
                                                [1, Highcharts.Color('GREY').brighten(-0.5).get('rgb')] //"#E8A317"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                 }
                            }
                         }
                    }
                },
```

**EDIT**

this is new js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/56zc1kzs/

now the radius of each point, when mouse hover, doesn't change. And so it's ok.

But the problem is that when hover, around the point, there will be a width with a color of tooltip's border .
How i can delete that border?

I hope that do you have understand me...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED...

to remove that shadow around a point when hover, i must to add this:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        halo: false
                    }
                }
            }
    },
```

**halo: false**

while if you want, is possible to customize **HALO**:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.states.hover.halo